# Programmatically set UIButton action throws exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, selector

I removed the action of a button defined in a framework and set it to a custom method and it seems to be throwing an exception.  Here is my removal and addition code:

```
[_loginView.logInView.signUpButton removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[_loginView.logInView.signUpButton  addTarget:self action:@selector(customViewMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

customViewMethod:

```
- (void)customViewMethod {

    [_loginView.view removeFromSuperview];

    [self.view addSubview:_signUpView.view];

}
```

Here is the exception:

`-[__NSCFDictionary customViewMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15691730`

Comment: How can `self` be an `NSDictionary`? My guess is that `self` is being deallocated before the signup button is tapped so the action ends up being called on the wrong object.

Comment: @rmaddy Not sure... that's why the exception makes no sense.  I don't have any code which would trigger the deallocation of my class.

Comment: Here's an easy way to know for sure. Add a `dealloc` method to whatever class `self` is in your posted code. Then set a breakpoint in the `dealloc` method. See if the breakpoint is reached before you tap on the button.

Comment: @rmaddy That was the case.  Thank you for giving me a straight up answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you are passing `self` as the button target of a button in another class, and given that the error indicates that the button handler is trying to call the action method on the wrong target (an `NSDictionary`), it's a good bet that `self` was deallocated after making itself the button's target. And now some random object is in the same memory location.

This can be confirmed by implementing the `dealloc` method on whatever class `self` is in your posted code. Then see if this `dealloc` is reached before the button is tapped on.

If so you know that `self` is being deallocated to soon. You need to keep a strong reference to it so it isn't deallocated too soon.

Answer (score 1):

Your view property, `self.view`, does not have a method named `customViewMethod`.  You might want to be adding the target to `self` (the view controller, not the view).

Comment: Please read updated question to make appropriate changes to your answer.

Comment: Could you post the customViewMethod code?

Comment: @AaronWojnowski There is no need to post that code. It's irrelevant to the question.